# What does this icon in available wifi mean?

Tags: macos, network, wifi

I just stumbled across something I never saw before.
When clicking on the the Wi-Fi icon in the menu bar at the top right of my screen, every available network has this "Wi-Fi icon" except one which has another icon and a "[?]" displayed as name, can someone explain what this is ?
I'm running macOS Sierra on a MacBook (8,1).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two-links symbol means Personal Hotspot. See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207354.

Comment: If the device has ever connected to an iPhone hotspot, it will continue to show that as available whenever the phone is near.  If the hotspot on the phone is turned off, it will still show available but fail to connect.

Answer (score 6):

That just means your Mac does not know how to display the network name. It could be an emoji that your computer doesn't know about.